# Calculating mean of a field using Python

Tags: arcpy, python, arcmap

I am very new to ArcGIS and Python. I want to do a basic calculation and find the mean of 1 field of a table.

The table is called Top 10 Tracks and the field in it called Path Length (km)
and there are 10 values in that field and I want to find mean of those values.
I have been googling but I couldn't find any information about this (maybe I wasn't googling enough)

Could you please help me write the python code for that or recommend a material I can read?

[image]

Comment: With the attribute table open you can right click the column header, select the Statistics button.  This will give you a pop-up box with summary statistics.  There is also a Summary Statistics tool in ArcToolbox.  The help for this tool has Python examples. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew how to do it in the ArcMap, I needed the python code :)

Comment: The link in my comment above opens a web page on the Summary Statistic tool.  There you will find the Python code using the arcpy library.  Do you mean you want to do it with Python but not use Arcpy?

Comment: Oh, no, I mean using Arcpy. Thank you very much, that link helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have several options. You can used the built-in function of ArcGIS field by right-clicking, choose statistics and you can see the mean and other values of your selected list.

Here is a screenshot of the Field Calculator

[image]

You could also, right-click the field, choose field calculator which will provide you with the option to create a [python script within ArcGIS](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm#GUID-9E423208-C918-442C-8D68-03AFB6C28709). You could use this example below to assist with calculating python

```
avg = sum(number_list)/len(number_list)
```

The number_list above can be replaced by your field name, here is a blog that covers more detail of the code above - https://www.guru99.com/find-average-list-python.html